# Errors and bugs in Ebizmarts SagePay Suite: Can not save order. Please try another payment option

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, sagepay

I am experiencing a few of these errors in my logs most days. Ebizmarts aren't any help in supporting the issue however is a difficult one to debug has happens very occasionally and I'm finding it difficult to reproduce:

```
["Ebizmarts\\SagePaySuite\\Model\\FormRequestManagement::getEncryptedRequest",158] []
[2018-10-16 18:55:02] SagePaySuiteLogger.Exception: Can not save order. Please try another payment option.
#0 /home/sites/magento/public_html/app/code/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Model/FormRequestManagement.php(135): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Helper\Checkout->placeOrder()
#1 [internal function]: Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Model\FormRequestManagement->getEncryptedRequest('fGegw585656R41i...')
#2 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(244): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))
#4 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#6 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#8 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#10 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#11 /home/sites/magento/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#12 {main}
```

Any one else experiencing errors like this with Ebizmarts SagePaySuite? Just trying to determine weather this is just my installation although stack trace doesn't seem to show anything interfering.

There are a few of these with different variations same function:

```
["Ebizmarts\\SagePaySuite\\Model\\FormRequestManagement::getEncryptedRequest",158] []
[2018-11-26 11:34:46] SagePaySuiteLogger.Exception: Order not available.
#0 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success->execute()
#1 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#2 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#3 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Ebizmarts/SagePaySuite/Controller/Form/Success/Interceptor.php(26): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#5 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Ebizmarts\SagePaySuite\Controller\Form\Success\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#8 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#14 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/sites/magento/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#16 /home/sites/magento/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#17 /home/sites/magento/public_html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#18 {main}
```

Comment: Try using Pi with DropIn. Is SAQ-A and you wont get that error.

Comment: Cheers. Yeah might give that a go. Do you know anything more about this error?

Comment: Hey, have you got any resolution to this? I am also facing the same issue. And it is very frustrating as it comes while placing an order.

Comment: Doesn't look like Ebizmarts can provide one. Pablo suggesting using the Pi method as a workaround which i'm going to try soon and see if it clears up. Tempted to move away from this module however support is poor even when payed for and errors are very regular so losing a lot of orders.

Comment: I also tried to get Ebizmarts support but they haven't provided any resolution yet. May I know which Magento version you are using. In my case, I am using Magento 2.2.6.

Comment: Had this issue all the way from 2.1.7 to 2.1.8 as far as i can tell.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this at stage server. Have you found steps to reproduce this? The issue seems random.

Comment: Yeah same for me completely random have tested and tested and it just doesn't seem to happen just see it in logs almost daily on live seems a bit random to me too i cannot see a pattern.

Comment: @GulshanMaurya No problem i'm sorry i cannot be any more help on this in the same boat as you. If you do come across anything, let me know if poss.

Comment: @harri did you manage to find out a solution? I was using the PI integration for some time, but with the latest module update, the drop-in on PI is not working as it should so have to move back to the FORM integration temporary :/ Seeing this error all the time and losing a lot of orders :/